# GitHub action: Repeat step with different environment values

Tags: github-actions

I've just created my first GitHub actions workflow which does handling of Docker images. It basically looks like this:

```
name: My Name
on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  whatever:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - env:
          TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE: node
          TARGET_TAG: 14-alpine
        run: |
            # ... ca 20 lines of code which reference ${TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE} and ${TARGET_TAG}
```

Now, I realized I want my action not to run just for the `node:14-alpine` image, but for several others images as well. I want, of course, avoid copy&pasting the code. So, I basically need to repeat the very same step but with different `env` values. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `matrix strategy`. Please fine below example,

```
jobs:
  whatever:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        TAG: [14-alpine, slim, buster, latest]
    steps:
      - env:
          TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE: node
          TARGET_TAG: ${{ matrix.TAG }}
        run: |
            # ... ca 20 lines of code which reference ${TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE} and ${TARGET_TAG}
```

Also below is one more example, of pushing to multiple ECR repos

```
jobs:
  build-app:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  strategy:
      matrix:
        Repo: [Repo1, Repo2, Repo3]
    steps:
    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials
    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    # see: https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login
    - name: Log in to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY:  ${{ matrix.Repo }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Comment: In your first example, you did just use the matrix for `TARGET_TAG`. How would it look like if both `TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE` and `TARGET_TAG` would be filled by matrix value? How can you group them together?

Comment: So, if we use both `TARGET_TAG` and `TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE` it'll create 4 jobs, 
```yml
TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE 1 & TARGET_TAG 1
TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE 1 & TARGET_TAG 2
TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE 2 & TARGET_TAG 2
TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE 2 & TARGET_TAG 1
```
Below is the yaml file for matrix on both `TAG` and `TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE`
```yml
    strategy:
      matrix:
        TAG: [14-alpine, slim, buster, latest]
        TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE: [node, circleci/node]
    steps:
      - env:
          TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE: ${{ matrix.TARGET_DOCKER_IMAGE }}
          TARGET_TAG: ${{ matrix.TAG }}
```